# Reset field values back to what is on saved document

Tags: xpages

I have a panel inside a repeat control with a domino document data source attached to it:

```
<xp:panel id="RepeatPanel">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument
            var="doc"
            formName="TestForm"
            action="editDocument"
            documentId="#{javascript:viewScope.docId}"
            concurrencyMode="force">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
```

If a user makes field changes, I want to have a Cancel button that will do a partial refresh and reset all the fields back to what is stored on the existing Notes document. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option "set partial execution mode" `execMode="partial"`:

```xml
<xp:button
    value="Cancel"
    id="button2">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="inputText1"
        execMode="partial">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Only the button (button2) gets partially executed = updated to server. Not so the part which gets partially refresh (inputText1 in example). This way inputText1 value doesn't get sent to server and server renders this part with the former data.

You can find more information about this option in the book "Mastering XPages: A Step-by-Step Guide to XPages Application Development and ... Second Edition" at page 920 and following.

As an **alternative**, you can reset the fields within refresh area with the values 
from backend document. Use `var docOld = document1.getDocument()` 
to get the backend document with the "old" values and assign old values to current data sources fields with
`document1.setValue("A", docOld.getItemValueString("A"))`:

```xml
    <xp:button
        id="buttonCancelRestore"
        value="Cancel Restore Values">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial"
            refreshId="panelRefresh"
            execMode="partial"
            execId="buttonCancelRestore">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                var docOld = document1.getDocument();
                document1.setValue("A", docOld.getItemValueString("A"));
                document1.setValue("B", docOld.getItemValueString("B"));
        }]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: It appears that this doesn't work if a field inside my panel does a partial refresh (I'm hiding/showing fields). If a partial refresh occurs and I click the cancel button with execMode="partial" the field values do not revert to the values on the document. Do you know a way around this?

Comment: Can you do the hiding/showing fields on client side only?

Comment: Probably could if it came down to that. Thanks.

Comment: Added an alternative to my answer. It allows you to refresh parts before the cancel and yet being able  to return to document's original values.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!